# Multiple Word Search not Working Correctly (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on a project that requires me to be able to search for multiple keywords in a file. For example, if I had a file with 100 occurrences of the word "Tomato", 500 for the word "Bread", and 20 for "Pickle", I would want to be able to search the file for "Tomato" and "Bread" and get the number of times it occurs in the file. I was able to find people with the same issue/question, but for other languages on this site.

I a working program  that allows me to search for the column name and tally how many times something shows up in that column, but I want to make something a bit more precise. Here is my code:

```
def start():
    location = raw_input("What is the folder containing the data you like processed located? ")
    #location = "C:/Code/Samples/Dates/2015-06-07/Large-Scale Data Parsing/Data Files"
    if os.path.exists(location) == True: #Tests to see if user entered a valid path
        file_extension = raw_input("What is the file type (.txt for example)? ")
        search_for(location,file_extension)
    else:
        print "I'm sorry, but the file location you have entered does not exist. Please try again."
        start()

def search_for(location,file_extension):
    querylist = []
    n = 5
    while n == 5:
        search_query = raw_input("What would you like to search for in each file? Use'Done' to indicate that you have finished your request. ")
        #list = ["CD90-N5722-15C", "CD90-NB810-4C", "CP90-N2475-8", "CD90-VN530-22B"]
        if search_query == "Done":
            print "Your queries are:",querylist
            print ""
            content = os.listdir(location)
            run(content,file_extension,location,querylist)
            n = 0
        else:
            querylist.append(search_query)
            continue


def run(content,file_extension,location,querylist):
    for item in content:
        if item.endswith(file_extension):
            search(location,item,querylist)
    quit()

def search(location,item,querylist):
    with open(os.path.join(location,item), 'r') as f:
        countlist = []
        for search in querylist: #any search value after the first one is incorrectly reporting "0"
            countsearch = 0
            for line in f:
                if search in line:
                    countsearch = countsearch + 1
            countlist.append(search)
            countlist.append(countsearch) #mechanism to update countsearch is not working for any value after the first
        print item, countlist

start()
```

If I use that code, the last part (def search) is not working correctly. Any time I put a search in, any search after the first one I enter in returns "0", despite there being up to 500,000 occurrences of the search word in a file.

I was also wondering, since I have to index 5 files with 1,000,000 lines each, if there was a way I could write either an additional function or something to count how many times "Lettuce" occurs over all the files.

I cannot post the files here due to their size and content. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

I also have this piece of code here. If I use this, I get the correct count of each, but it would be much better to have a user be able to enter as many searches as they want:

```
def check_start():
    #location = raw_input("What is the folder containing the data you like processed located? ")
    location = "C:/Code/Samples/Dates/2015-06-07/Large-Scale Data Parsing/Data Files"
    content = os.listdir(location)
    for item in content:
        if item.endswith("processed"):
             countcol1 = 0
             countcol2 = 0
             countcol3 = 0
             countcol4 = 0
             #print os.path.join(currentdir,item)
             with open(os.path.join(location,item), 'r') as f:
                  for line in f:
                      if "CD90-N5722-15C" in line:
                          countcol1 = countcol1 + 1
                      if "CD90-NB810-4C" in line:
                          countcol2 = countcol2 + 1
                      if "CP90-N2475-8" in line:
                          countcol3 = countcol3 + 1
                      if "CD90-VN530-22B" in line:
                          countcol4 = countcol4 + 1
             print item, "CD90-N5722-15C", countcol1, "CD90-NB810-4C", countcol2, "CP90-N2475-8", countcol3, "CD90-VN530-22B", countcol4
```

Comment: Can you fix your code indentation please.

Comment: @SiHa Thanks for letting me know, but I can't see where it is off. Could you let me know please?

Comment: Looks like you need to indent the lines after your function definitions.

Comment: Oh! I didn't realize they didn't automatically indent on the site. On my code they are perfectly fine (I think this might be because I use tab).

Comment: Yeah, that happens. I'm traumatized by the tab button.

About your code, in the second example that works, it looks like you're counting instances of the term "CD90-N5722-15C", "CD90-NB810-4C", etc. If that's so, couldn't you replace those hardcoded values with variables? You could define those variables with raw_input so that a user can enter their own search terms.

Comment: @alfonso what do you mean by that? The values "CD90-N5722-15C", etc. have a meaning in our company. Could you post an example of what you are saying please?

Comment: Sure, will do. I'll put it down as an answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to iterate over your file more than once. After the first time, the file pointer is at the end so subsequent searches will fail because there's nothing left to read.

If you add the line:

`f.seek(0)`, this will reset the pointer before every read:

```
def search(location,item,querylist):
    with open(os.path.join(location,item), 'r') as f:
        countlist = []
        for search in querylist: #any search value after the first one is incorrectly reporting "0"
            countsearch = 0
            for line in f:
                if search in line:
                    countsearch = countsearch + 1
            countlist.append(search)
            countlist.append(countsearch) #mechanism to update countsearch is not working for any value after the first
            f.seek(0)
    print item, countlist
```

PS. I've guessed at the indentation... You **really** shouldn't use tabs.

Comment: Sorry! I really should use spaces but Pycharm can't tell the difference (it substitutes 4 spaces for a tab in the program). The f.seek(0) method didn't work for me, I'm still returning 0 for any value after the first: `out-30000000.txt.processed ['CD90-N5722-15C', 438956, 'CD90-NB810-4C', 0]`

Comment: @TobyTobyo, the seek was is the wrong place, all it was doing was seeking to the start of the file when it was already at the start, you need to seek after each iteration over f

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I realised that the first seek was unneccesary when I put it there, but thought it made it clearer. Did it really warranting editing to move it?

Comment: @SiHa, you only had one seek, your code did not work until I edited it so not sure what you mean exactly. How would a seek right after you open the file affect the code in the loop?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Oh bugger - was it outside the loop? I'm embarrassed now. Thanks for the edit - I'll slope away quietly now...

Comment: @SiHa, it was right after you opened the file so basically was a code doorstop ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get your question completely, but how about something like this?

```
def check_start():

    raw_search_terms = raw_input('Enter search terms seperated by a comma:')
    search_term_list = raw_search_terms.split(',')

    #location = raw_input("What is the folder containing the data you like processed located? ")
    location = "C:/Code/Samples/Dates/2015-06-07/Large-Scale Data Parsing/Data Files"
    content = os.listdir(location)

    for item in content:
        if item.endswith("processed"):
            # create a dictionary of search terms with their counts (initialized to 0)
            search_term_count_dict = dict(zip(search_term_list, [0 for s in search_term_list]))

            for line in f:
                for s in search_term_list:
                    if s in line:
                        search_term_count_dict[s] += 1



        print item
        for key, value in search_term_count_dict.iteritems() :
            print key, value
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it wasn't quite what I was looking for. Siha and Cunningham's method is what I was looking for. Thank you very much for the answer though!